# Use Google Sheet Script to Roll Up Multiple GA4 Properties

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using this [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analyticsdata) to pull GA4 data into a google sheet via the Google Analytics Data API.  Here is the code:

```
function runReport() {
 
  const propertyId = '111222333';

  try {
    const metric = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
    metric.name = 'Event count';
    metric.name = 'Total users';
    metric.name = 'Sessions';
   
    const dimension = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
    dimension.name = 'Event name';
    dimension.name = 'Link URL';
    dimension.name = 'Date';
    dimension.name = 'Stream name';

    const dateRange = AnalyticsData.newDateRange();
    dateRange.startDate = '2022-05-01';
    dateRange.endDate = 'today';

    const request = AnalyticsData.newRunReportRequest();
    request.dimensions = [dimension];
    request.metrics = [metric];
    request.dateRanges = dateRange;

    const report = AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport(request,
        'properties/' + propertyId);
    if (!report.rows) {
      Logger.log('No rows returned.');
      return;
    }
```

Edit: I'd like to create a script to generate an output like this:

[image]

The multiple properties are:

- 111222333
- 222333444
- 444555666
- 777888999

Is it possible to adjust this script to pull data from multiple GA4 properties and output into one dataset?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] we cant help you decide that without seeing your code

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal from `Is it possible to adjust this script to pull data from multiple GA4 properties to create a roll-up dataset?`. Can you provide your expected result as an image?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I made some edits and added a picture to help clarify.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your added images, when you want to retrieve the values from multiple property IDs, multiple values are returned from each property ID. But, in your showing image of `Edit: I'd like to create a script to generate an output like this:`, one property ID has only one row. So, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, when you include `@username` in your reply comment, the user can notice your reply comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in the code:

```
request.dimensions = [{name: 'transactionId'}, {name : 'sessionSourceMedium'}, {name : 'sessionCampaignName'}]
```

All available dimensions you can find here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema